# How can I include all the coordinates in the MapBox by adjusting the zoom level?

Tags: annotations, coordinates, zooming, mapbox

The code I have used is:

```
let bounds = MGLCoordinateBounds(
    sw: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7115, longitude: 10.3725),
    ne: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7318, longitude: 10.4222))
    mapView.setVisibleCoordinateBounds(bounds, animated: false)
```

I have 3 annotation and I want to see the 3 annotaion in the mapBox by adjusting the zoom level. Please help me to find it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is method on `MGLMapView` that you can use:

```
func showAllAnnotations() {
    guard let annotations = mapView.annotations else { return }

    // Either this...
    mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 40, left: 35, bottom: 35, right: 35), animated: true)
    // or this.
    mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
}
```